# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with c# String via OracleParameter, quote scaping

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate

I'm currently working on an assignment. I need to be able to execute a SQL statement via an stored procedure in Oracle.

I can do it within SQLDeveloper, using something like:

```
declare
n varchar2(100);
begin
   n := 'insert into REGION(ID_REGION, NOMBRE_REGION) values(10,''DESAMPA'')';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE n;
end;
```

The region table is pretty simple, an `id` and a `varchar`. That block works in SQL Developer.
However, I need to call it inside this stored procedure:

```
Procedure Hacer_Query (P_Query in Varchar2)
AS
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE P_Query;
END;
```

This procedure also works. However, I'm having trouble calling this procedure from C#. For some reason, I'm getting ORA-00900 invalid SQL errors. I believe it may have something to do with the scaping of the single quotes, since

```
SELECT nombre_region FROM REGION:
```

Works from C# when I store it in a cursor. I'm using OracleParameter to send this to the procedure:

```
"insert into REGION(ID_REGION, NOMBRE_REGION) values(11,'DESAMPA')"
```

Is there some special way to do this? Any special syntax for the quotes?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'insert into REGION(ID_REGION, NOMBRE_REGION) values(10,''DESAMPA'')';
```

does not work. It seems it only works from within a block. I feel like I'm missing something here...

Nevermind that last part, I am now calling it from a block. Still doesn't work from C# however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make a function that calls it, and use this function in your Stored Procedure.

Function sounds like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SISADMIN.EXECSQL(SQL1 VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  FUNCTIONRESULT VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL1;
  RETURN(FUNCTIONRESULT);
END EXECSQL;

DECLARE 
  TESTE VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN 
  TESTE :=  SISADMIN.EXECSQL('insert into REGION(ID_REGION, NOMBRE_REGION) values(10,''DESAMPA'')');
END;
```

The function is not perfect, but you can adjust it.. well, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You really should look at using parameters to your stored procedure instead of passing the whole sql string.  It will take care of the escaping problem and not be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm pretty aware of that. The problem is that I don't know the SQL before runtime. I need to be able to execute any SQL that the user enters in a text field.

Comment: Any SQL ? What if user enters `drop table REGION` ? Or maybe `UPDATE TABLE users SET password = 'xxx' WHERE username = 'admin' ` ?

Comment: I am aware of every security problem that comes with this :-D and I appreciate your concerns. As I said in the question, it's an assignment, not a production project.